# How would / could I the center text, with out the ugly formatting?

Tags: css, html, css-float

How would / could I the center text, with out the ugly formatting?

I've tried different margins, but so far no luck...

Basically, I'm looking for a left aligned text, that's centered. (Though it still has to be responsive.

[Left-ish Aligned, but not centered.](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-keroatjx9Vo/VN7gGtt-MpI/AAAAAAAAVOM/vOk5rO6DsK0/w758-h507-no/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-02-13%2Bat%2B9.41.08%2BPM.png)

[Centered, But not aligned properly, still has the ugly centered format.](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-RtlMzf6Nf2k/VN7gcCh_fkI/AAAAAAAAVOg/6uJK-ovwjr4/w1092-h494-no/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-02-13%2Bat%2B9.42.42%2BPM.png)

1

```
section{
line-height:1.5em;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding:35px;
width:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#FFF;
background: rgba(176,224,230,.3);
text-align:center;
}
```

2

```
section{
line-height:1.5em;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding:35px;
width:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#FFF;
background: rgba(176,224,230,.3);
}
```

Any advice / help would be awesome, thanks!!

Comment: show us your html code in the question as well. It'll help get answers for your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Inner content (`p`) has `display: inline-block` or `inline`, the parent element's content is centered.

```
<div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaa<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet bfds<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
</div>

<style>
    div {background: lightblue; text-align: center;}
    p {display: inline-block; text-align: left; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2x5kwy7n/1/

Comment: Thank you so much!! This basically fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I am aligning text in centre by this css code, which has background image and centred  Text align.

```
.footer{  
    background: url(../images/footer/footer.png) no-repeat;  
    background-position: center;  
    padding: 30px 0px 70px 0px;  
    color: #ffffff;  
    text-align: center;  
    margin-left: -2%;  
    margin-right: -2%;  

}
```

Comment: But Eric don't want/need to use `text-align: center;`, he wrote that in question. Don'e need to set there a `background`, set fixed `padding` values and negative margins.